# Acumatica - IT team wants to know the IP of the server but it's a Saas deployment

Tags: smtp, cloud, acumatica, saas, erp

Question, not necessarily specific to Acumatica Cloud ERP.

The IT team is asking to whitelist the Acumatica server's IP for SMTP relay. But this is a Saas deployment and I'm not even sure the IP address would be consistent, and since we don't log INTO the server I'm not able to get the IP address (I think). Is there a way around this? How do you handle it?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it needs to be Acumatica server IP?
Could it be the SMTP server that they're after?

If so, they are listed in `Configuration->Email->Manage->System Emails Account`:
[image]

You can resolve the host names to IP addresses if required.